# How install the new SubtitleEdit 3.6.7 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

Please help .. I want install SubtitleEdit 3.6.7 on Ubuntu 22.04 with Wine or PlayOnlinux but needs netframework 4.7.2 how to install

Comment: Have you checked the Wine site to see if the app is supported by Wine? https://appdb.winehq.org/

Answer (score 0):

Download the portable version of SubtitleEdit (SE) and run the command bellow

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete libhunspell-dev libmpv-dev tesseract-ocr vlc ffmpeg
```

By running this command you will install the needed library including mono (dot net framework alternative in linux)

And for running SE, run:

```
mono SubtitleEdit.exe
```

**Bonus**

There is a package called wine-mono in other distros, its a mono installer for wine, but its not on the ubunto repos.

You can find more about how to install it,  [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono#Installing).